# How do 3 points define a plane?

Tags: combinatorics, euclidean-geometry

I was solving a combinatorics problem which asked me to find the number of planes that can be constructed from a set of 25 points such that no 4 points in the set of 25 points are co-planar and then I researched about the questions as to how many points define a plane in general and came across the following link - https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090930201928AAL3FeN which says 3 points are sufficient to define a plane. Can someone try to explain more generally using some examples as to how 3 points define a plane?

Comment: Since this has gotten bumped: Two distinct points determine a unique line in space; a third point not on this line determines a unique plane. If you watch dust motes drifting in a shaft of sun, the claim will quickly become intuitively obvious. :)

Comment: ...three **noncollinear** points, yes. In proper Euclidean geometry, this is actually a postulate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the vector equation of a plane

> $$P:\; \mathbf{p}+t\mathbf{u}+s\mathbf{v}$$

it's simple:  you need two vectors, $\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}$, (linearly independent) and a point, $\mathbf{p}$. Given three points, we can take any two of them (assuming they're non collinear, which of course is necessary) and write out their coordinate differences to form vectors which we can use to write the plane. So what's the plane passing through say the points $(0,0,0), (1,0,0), (0,1,0)$?

Well, let's use the point $\mathbf{p}=(0,0,0)$ as the base point and form our direction vectors $\mathbf{u}=(1,0,0)-(0,0,0)=(1,0,0)$ and $\mathbf{v}=(1,0,0)-(0,1,0)=(1,-1,0)$ (you can pick any two of them, I chose these two for ease of computation and to illustrate the computation where both vectors don't end up looking exactly the same as the point) This gives us a plane equation:

> $$P:\; t\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}+s\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}=\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3 : x=t+s,\, y= -s,\, z=0\}$$

In more dimensions you do the same procedure, only with more coordinates. Let me demonstrate in $\Bbb R^4$ with points $(1,0,0,0),(3,0,0,0), (0,1,0,0)$ then I'll choose my base point to be $\mathbf{p}=(1,0,0,0)$ and my two direction vectors $\mathbf{u}=(3,0,0,0)-(1,0,0,0)=(2,0,0,0)$ and $\mathbf{v}=(3,0,0,0)-(0,1,0,0)=(3,-1,0,0)$ giving us

$$P:\; \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\0\end{pmatrix}+t\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\0\end{pmatrix}+s\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\-1\\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$=\{(x,y,z,w)\in\Bbb R^4: x=1+2t+3s,\, y= 2t-s,\, z=w=0\}.$$

Now there's a problem with $4$ points, namely the same problem with why $3$ points don't always determine a line:  if, for example, you asked what line are the points $(0,0,0),\, (1,0,0), \, (0,1,0)$ was in the first question you'd laugh at me. Why? Because there is no such line:  necessarily all points on a line have to have the same direction vector, since--by definition--a line is a set of points in $\Bbb R^n$ such that:

> $$\ell:\; \mathbf{p}+t\mathbf{v}$$

for some base point, $\mathbf{p}$ and direction vector, $\mathbf{v}$.

When you have three points, and try to make all of them fit that equation, you get a system of equations that might not be solvable because there are too many restrictions, just like asking for positive numbers less than $-2$, i.e

> $$\{x\in\Bbb R : x>0\text{ and } x<-2\}$$

You can ask for positive numbers (there are a TON) and you can ask for those less than $-2$, but just because you have two conditions doesn't mean they're compatible, it sometimes ends up that you some of them try and fight the others. The same is true with $4$ points:  since $3$ points determine the plane, it can be that you can pick another point in space which is *not* on that plane (unless you're working in $\Bbb R^2$ this is always possible). In which case, if you move your plane to include the missing points, you've got to move it away from the three you've already set up. Now, as before you can always keep three of the four, but there's no guarantee you can get them all:  most times it just isn't in the cards.

Comment: The answer to the combinatorics question is like C(25,3) which I am not able to see why, can't 4 points define a plane? if yes then the answer should be C(25,3) + C(25,4) isn't it?

Comment: @AnkitSablok I'll edit to show why 4 points are a problem.

Comment: Can you like give a non mathematical example to show why 4 points are a problem and 3 are not and for that matter is it a generalization that higher number of points pose problems to define a plane?

Comment: @AnkitSablok I don't know what you mean by "non-mathematical example:" planes are mathematical objects, how can I give you an example of a mathematical thing which is not mathematical?

Comment: An aside: Isn't a *single* point sufficient to describe a plane? (Its normalized difference to the origin is the normal of the plane, and its distance to the origin is the distance of the plane to the origin - did I miss some degree of freedom here...?)

Comment: @Marco13 A single point has many planes passing through it. The construction you describe seems to want to treat a point as a vector in $\Bbb R^3$ and use it as a normal to a given plane, but even that is insufficient as there are many parallel planes, and it only would work even that well in $\Bbb R^3$ where two-dimensional subspaces are dual to one-dimensional subspaces.

The main drive here is that there is a plane and it is *uniquely determined* by three points inside of itself, regardless of the ambient space.

Comment: There are many planes passing through the point, but fewer whose normal is equal to the point when it is interpreted as a vector. And there are many parallel planes with such a normal vector, but only one that has the same distance to the origin as the point has. So in R^3, a single point would suffice, but I guess *that* was the invalid assumption that I made: For a general, 2D plane in any R^n, one needs the additional *two* vectors, of course. That's basically the definition of **"2D"**, so it's not too surprising...

Comment: Yes, you're technically right, but in a way which is misleading to call "right" in a philosophical sense:  one can come up with arbitrary rules to assign to things other things, but unless it has some sort of *independence* of choices made, it's not called "canonical," i.e. it's acknowledged as mostly arbitrary, even when it relates to other common quantities. I say this mostly because, while clever, it's not helpful or generalizable for the question at-hand, so mentioning it does more harm than good in this instance. I'm not calling it *bad*, I think it's kind of neat, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

With 3 points defining a plane, the number of combinations is $^{25}C_3.   $ 
A surface going through 4 points has Gauss curvature positive or negative, never zero unless the fourth point is in the plane determined by the first three.